# what is the context for a custom adapter in onScrollListener

Tags: android, android-emulator

usually we use

```
adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.feed_items, R.id.label, feed_products_list);
```

but if we are in setOnScrollListener method or something like that it wont allow 'this' as parameter so what should i give thr?
Should i add a new constructor for my custom array adapter with onScrollListener as parameter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use three things,

```
MyActivity.this
getApplicationContext()
this
```

Use them wisely :)

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do in this circumstance is create a class level private static instance variable for the activity class and set it up in onCreate.

that variable can then be used as a context inside private inner onClickListeners etc

edited to provide an example

```
Public class MyClass extends Activity {

private static MyClass instance;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
...
    mVideoView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(instance, R.layout.feed_items, R.id.label, feed_products_list);
....
```

etc

Comment: private context someContext;........then in onCreate()...someContext = this;  ????